# URL redirected when using file_get_contents

Tags: php, web-scraping

When I am using file_get_contents() function it is redirected to home page.

```
$url = "http://convergecom.com.br/pesquisa-guia-tela-viva?ddlCidade=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%7CSP&pagenum=14";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
exit;
```

It is displaying content of home page(http://convergecom.com.br/pesquisa-guia-tela-viva). Following is the homepage.

```
$url = "http://convergecom.com.br/pesquisa-guia-tela-viva";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
exit;
```

Both returning same content.
Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the server is redirecting the request to this URL (http://convergecom.com.br/pesquisa-guia-tela-viva?ddlCidade=S%C3%A3o+Paulo%7CSP&pagenum=1). If you try to access it directly via browser, you'll get redirected. Maybe it uses some kind of session variable to validate that the user is not trying to access it directly, or maybe there's an error on the request parameters.

It doesn't seem to be an issue in your code, though.

Comment: When I paste this url in browser it display list of records but when I am using it with file_get_content it display home page content. So there is not any possibility of session set or request parameter.

Comment: That's weird. I tried pasting this URL on both Chromium and Firefox, and it still redirected me to http://convergecom.com.br/pesquisa-guia-tela-viva/. Maybe they set a cookie? What parameter do you use on the search to reach this page?

Comment: You are right. When I paste the URL in the browser, at that time in other that URL is opened. So I didn't redirect to other tab but when I closed that tab, It redirect to home page.